# Custom Product Options Not Displaying After Migration From 1.9.X to 2.3.X

Tags: magento-1.9, magento2.3

I have migrated data from my old Magento store 1.9.3.6 to the new Magento 2.3.4 . everything is migrated properly instead of custom options of products. my old store have custom options with products but after migration it is not visible in magento 2. screen from magento 1 version
[image]

Screen from magento 2 Version
[image]

Meanwhile if i am adding this from admin panel then it's visible properly.
[image]

Can someone help me about fixing this issue.
Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I also faced the issue.

After doing some investigation I found that has_options column has 0 but product have at least one option associated in the product options table.

I didn't find a scenario to reproduce but it seems the product options were imported by any third party extension or migrated from an older version of Magento.

Re-saving product resolves the issue because there is a check at before product save that updates has_options value to 1.

So, I prepared below query to find all such products and managed to save all the resulted products.

```
SELECT * FROM `catalog_product_entity` WHERE entity_id in (SELECT product_id FROM `catalog_product_option`) and has_options = 0
```

I hope this may help someone facing the same issue.

Please accept as a solution if this will work for you.

Comment: i have checked with this option but it didn't worked.

Comment: please just try to save product only(don't add options) and check in frontend. after that are you getting option on detail page?

Comment: if i am adding product options from admin panel then it's visible properly. there is no issue. but i am looking for old options which are available in magento 1 version , it should be displayed in latest version. i hope you understand my point.

Comment: I get your issue brother properly...please first check in database its migrated or not.

Comment: in database it's migrated successfully

Answer (score 0):

Run command line: php bin/magento indexer:reindex